# Repeat data in Jasper Reports?

Tags: parameters, report, barcode

I have a little problem about Jasper Reports. I'm designing this specific report using a para meter to generate a bar code. when it's running,user will be asked to enter a word or something and then the report will generate a barcode using that text or number. Now what I wanna do is to make copies of that barcode in the same page as much as user want. how can I do it? any help will be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly ,you could design like this,two kinds of elements in your *.jasper file.One is a filed ,which user could write the number of barcode.The others are barcodes in *.jasper,all the barcode are hidden before user enter the number.

2.Sceondly.In you code ,according to user enter's number to show barcode.

3.Have fun!